# how to get response from email using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, gmail-api, mailgun

I am sending an email to a user using Mail.

```
public function sendEmail($post, $contactEmail)
    {
        Mail::to($contactEmail)->send(new EmailAboutNewPost($post));
    }
```

How can I get the user's response?
And process in your application,
When he presses the button "Answer" in his letter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQFC2.png)

tried using mailgag webhooks

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no way to tell if a customer hits Reply on a message. Mailgun has the ability to check opens and clicks if you're using their mailing list features, but for a single email, they'll only be able to tell you the deliverability. You'll only know if they clicked Reply if the email shows up in the mailbox of the address you used for the Reply-To or From address.

Answer (score -1):

Set a **Reply-To address** so that when the user clicks **Reply** in their email client the reply will be sent to this address.

```
Mail::to($contactEmail)->send(new EmailAboutNewPost($post))->replyTo($replyToAddress);
```